# Android Popup call function

Tags: android, popup, popupmenu

forgive me but i´m just a beginner in android programming ! I want to make a popup menu and after clicking an item i want to call die public void function  RefreshMenuItems(2); but nothing happens. I hope somebody can tell me how i can call a functioin from the main activity

here is my code :

```js
/**
 * A Button that acts as the view element for the popup menu.
 */
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
/**
 * Step 1: Create a new instance of popup menu
 */
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, btn);
/**
 * Step 2: Inflate the menu resource. Here the menu resource is
 * defined in the res/menu project folder
 */
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
/**
 * Step 3: Call show() method on the popup menu to display the
 * menu when the button is clicked.
 */
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popupMenu.show();
    }
});
/**
 *  Handle menu item clicks
 */
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
    new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_red:
                // Here i want to call the function but nothing happens ??
                RefreshMenuItems(2);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_blue:
                btn.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_green:
                btn.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
                 break;
            }
            return true; 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you describe more about RefreshMenuItems? Is it not in your main activity? Does it return any error?

Comment: the RefreshMenuItems shows products with titel, image, price in a horizontal sroll view

Comment: no error but in console i get Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has alreade been disposed ...

Comment: anybody here who can tell me why i cannot call the function ? im not able to start a new intent too :(